# jquery add dynamically li with input filed

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, dynamic

I'm trying to add a li to my `ul` with a input field.

Important is that the input id is created dynamically.

```html
<li>
  <input id="txtMenuElement1" type="text" />
</li>
```

This is my function:

```js
function addNewMenuElement() {
  if ($('#hfCountMenueElemente').val() < 9) {
    i += 1;
    $('#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen').append($('<li><input />', { type: 'text', id: 'name' + i }, '</li>'));
    $('#hfCountMenueElemente').val(i);
  } else {
    var notification = $find('<%=rnfMaximalMenuElemente.ClientID %>');
    notification.show();
  }
}
```

If I do it like this, my generated code look like this:

```html
<li>
  <input />
</li>
```

So, it ignores the attributes for the input field.

Does anyone have a idea how I'm doing this in the right way?

Thanks for reading. Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $x = $('<li/>');
var $y = $('<input />', { type: 'text', id: 'name' + i});
$x.append($y);
$("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append($x);
```

another code

```
$("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append('<li><input type="text" id="name"' + i +"/> </li>");
```

problem with your code

```
$("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append($("<li><input />", { type: "text", id: "name" + i}, "</li>"));
```

`$("<li><input />",` you are assigning text and name.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
i= 0;
function addNewMenuElement() {
        i += 1;
        $("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append("<li><input type='text'  id= 'name" + i + "'/></li>");
        $('#hfCountMenueElemente').val(i);

}

$('.click-me').click(function(){
       addNewMenuElement();
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gBSXG/%5d)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var $li = $('<li/>'),
    $input = $('<input />', { type: 'text', id: 'name' + i});

$li.append($input);

$("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append($li);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work. You were trying to set the properties to a not so well defined element (both `li` and `input` being added at the same time). Also is good to define the `input` name, not just its id.

```
function addNewMenuElement() {
    var i = $('#hfCountMenueElemente').prop("value");

    if (i < 9) {
        i++;

        $("#ulMenueElementeHinzufuegen").append($("<li />")).append($("<input />", {
            type: "text",
            id: "name" + i.toString(),
            name: "name" + i.toString()
        }));

        $('#hfCountMenueElemente').prop("value", i);
    } else {
        var notification = $.find("<%=rnfMaximalMenuElemente.ClientID %>");
        notification.show();
    };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tQfbv/